# VBSCRIPT enumerate Read-Only Domain Controllers

Tags: active-directory, vbscript

How can I list all Read Only Domain Controllers that are listed in Active Directory using VBScript?

Comment: the post by matthewk is the reason not to use vbs anymore to verbose and if you were not cutting and pasting you'd be troubleshooting it for awhile.

Comment: single line command dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(msDS-IsRodc=true))" -attr cn -limit 0

Answer (score 1):

http://www.msresource.net/code/find_all_read_only_domain_controllers_%28rodc%29_in_the_domain.html

```
' *********************************************************
' DS-Ex-FindAllRODCs V01.00.00vbs
' 
' Example script to illustrate how to locate all RODCs in
' a forest.  Script is more lengthy than expected due to 
' error handling, debug info., etc.
' 
' Version:  V01.00.00vbs
' Written:  03-12-2007
' 
' *********************************************************

Option Explicit

' Variant used as a constant to determine whether or not the
' print sub-routine should actually print to the screen (console)
Dim printInfoToConsole : printInfoToConsole = True
Dim printDebugInfoToConsole : printDebugInfoToConsole = False


' ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** 
'   ----- MAIN BODY OF SCRIPT -----

On Error Resume Next
    Dim dse : Set dse = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim result : result = verifyError(Err)
    If Not result Then printDirectoryInfo(dse)
On Error Goto 0

' testing only
Dim hostname : hostname = dse.get("dNSHostName")
Dim rodc, rodcs() : rodcs = getRODCs(hostname)
For Each rodc In rodcs
    print(rodc)
Next

'   ----- END OF "MAIN" (subs and funcs follow)
' ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** 


Private Function getRODCs(targetHostname) ' as String()
    Dim rootDse, connection, command, recordSet
    Dim ldapQuery, ldapBase, ldapFilter, ldapAttrs, ldapScope ' as string

    If Not ((targetHostname = "") And (Right(targetHostname, 1) = "/"))Then
        targetHostname = targetHostname & "/"
    End If

    Set rootDse = GetObject("LDAP://" & targetHostname & "RootDSE")
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    ' define filter
    ldapBase    = "<GC://" & rootDse.get("rootDomainNamingContext") & ">;"
    ldapFilter= "(&(objectCategory=computer)(msDS-IsRodc=true));"
    ldapAttrs   = "distinguishedName,cn,memberOf,displayName;"
    ldapScope   = "SubTree"

    ldapQuery   = ldapBase & ldapFilter & ldapAttrs & ldapScope

    ' configure ADO
    connection.provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    connection.open "Active Directory Provider"

    command.activeConnection = connection
    command.CommandText = ldapQuery

    command.properties("Page Size") = 100
    command.properties("Size Limit") = 10000
    command.properties("Cache Results") = False

    ' execute the command
    Set recordSet = command.execute

    If(recordSet.EOF)Then quit"No RODCs in the forest"
    recordSet.MoveFirst

    While Not recordSet.EOF
        Dim i, j ' as int

        If Not IsNull(recordSet.fields("distinguishedName").value)Then _
            print "DN: " & recordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value

        For i = 1 To recordSet.Fields.Count - 1
            If(TypeName(recordSet.Fields(i).Value) = "Variant()" And Not (IsNull(recordSet.Fields(i).Value)))Then
                print "  " & recordSet.Fields(i).Name & " ("  & _
                    UBound(recordSet.Fields(i).Value) & "):"

                Dim item : For Each item In recordSet.Fields(i).Value
                    print "    > " & item
                Next

                print ""
            Else
                    print "  " & recordSet.Fields(i).Name & ": " & recordSet.Fields(i).Value

            End If
        Next

        print""
        recordSet.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' testing
    Dim str() : getRODCs = str
End Function


' *******************************************************************
' Print-Directory-Info
' 
' Sub prints the DC that is being used and the level of the 
' directory service, e.g. Win2003 or ADAM
' 
' 
' Note.  Sub calls function Get-DS-Functionality
' 
' *******************************************************************
Private Sub printDirectoryInfo(oRootDse)
    Dim sServer, sDSFunctionality

    sServer = oRootDse.get("dNSHostName")
    sDSFunctionality = _
        getDSFunctionality(oRootDse.get("domainControllerFunctionality"), _
            oRootDse.get("supportedCapabilities"))

    print"Using server: " & sServer
    print"Directory: " & sDSFunctionality & vbCrLf
End Sub



' *******************************************************************
' Get-DS-Functionality
' 
' Get the domain functional level for info. purposes.  Function 
' returns a string defining the current value of the DC queried 
' (via serverless bind)
' 
' *******************************************************************
Private Function getDSFunctionality(iDSFunctionality, _
        cSupportedCapabilities)

    ' supportedCapability of an ADAM directory.  Presence indicates AD LDS
    Const LDAP_CAP_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_ADAM_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1851"

    ' supportedCapability of an RODC.  Presence indictes DS is RO
    Const ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_PARTIAL_SECRETS  = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1920" ' as string

    Dim oBase, dsf, nTMixedDomain, supportedCapability, ldsFlag, rodcFlag
    ldsFlag = False
    rodcFlag = False

    For Each supportedCapability In cSupportedCapabilities
        If(supportedCapability = _
            LDAP_CAP_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_ADAM_OID)Then _
                ldsFlag = True

        If(supportedCapability = _
            ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_PARTIAL_SECRETS)Then _
                rodcFlag = True
    Next

    If(ldsFlag)Then
        If(iDSFunctionality > 2)Then
            dsf = "Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)"
        Else
            dsf = "Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)"
        End If
    Else
        Select Case iDSFunctionality
            Case 0
                Set oBase = oRootDse.get("defaultNamingContext")
                nTMixedDomain = oBase.get("nTMixedDomain")

                If(nTMixedDomain=1)Then
                    dsf = "Windows 2000 Native"
                Else
                    dsf = "Windows 2000 Mixed"
                End If

            Case 1
                dsf = "Windows Server 2003 Interim"

            Case 2
                dsf = "Windows Server 2003"

            Case 3
                dsf = "Windows Server 2008"

        End Select
    End If

    If(rodcFlag)Then dsf = dsf  & " (RODC)"

    getDSFunctionality = dsf
End Function


' Verify-Error(ByVal _err as Error-Object)
' 
' Function checks to see if the passed error object is in
' an error state and, if so, returns TRUE, otherwise
' returns FALSE
' 
Private Function verifyError(oErr)
    Dim inErrorState : inErrorState = False

    If(oErr.number <> 0)Then _
        inErrorState = True

    dbgPrint"Verify-Error::inErrorState=" & inErrorState

    verifyError = inErrorState
End Function


' Handle-Error(ByVal _err as Error-Object)
' 
' Sub prints the error number and, if present, description
' to the console if the passed argument print is enabled 
' and terminates, if the passed argument fatal is enabled.
' 
Private Sub handleError(oErr, fatal, shouldPrint)
    On Error Goto 0

    dbgPrint"Handle-Error::shouldPrint=" & shouldPrint
    dbgPrint"Handle-Error::fatal=" & fatal

    Dim errorMessage ' as string
    errorMessage = "Error: " & oErr.number

    If Not (oErr.description="")Then _
        errorMessage = errorMessage & "Details: " & _
            oErr.description & vbCrLf

    If(shouldPrint)Then print errorMessage

    If(fatal)Then 
        print vbCrLf & "Error requires premature termination.  " & _
            "Exiting script..." & vbCrLf

        WScript.Quit(-1)
    End If
End Sub

' Print(ByVal printStr as String)
'  
' Sub prints the passed string to the console if the constant-
' esq variant Print-Info-To-Console is TRUE.  Otherwise the
' passed string is logged (if implemented) or ignored.
' 
Private Sub print(printStr)
    If(printInfoToConsole)Then
        WScript.Echo(printStr)
    Else
        ' code to write to file goes here...
    End If  
End Sub

Private Sub dbgPrint(debugStr)
    If(printDebugInfoToConsole)Then _
        WScript.Echo(" [script-debug-string] " & debugStr)
End Sub


Private Sub quit(quitStr)
    print(quitStr)
    WScript.Quit(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filter = “(&(ObjectClass=attributeSchema)(SearchFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512))”
```

or as listed in the other post

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(msDS-IsRodc=true))"   

$ds = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"",$filter)  
$ds.PageSize = 1000  
$rodc = $ds.FindAll()  
$rodc
```

powershell version but I can't test it right now

Comment: +1 The nice thing about learning how to use LDAP queries is that not only are they very flexible, but they may be used in may different scripting/programming languages.